# Что за синтаксис? (префикс – нижнее подчеркивание)

Tags: javascript, синтаксис

Во многих языках программирования встречаю: префикс переменных или функций — нижнее подчёркивание. Для чего это?

Например, вот отрывок из скрипта vk:

```
if (vk.al != 3 || vk.navPrefix != '!') {
    ___to = ___htest.replace(/^(\/|!)/, '');
```

Или

```
int ____MAX, ...
```

Почему так много? Понимаю, когда одно ставят, иногда удобно в таких случаях:

```
int x = ...;
int _x = ...;
```

Comment: Ну, например, в Python для перегрузки операторов добавляются символы нижнего подчёркивания, чтобы обозначить важность метода. Например __init__ - конструктор класса, __add__ - перегрузка бинарного умножения объектов класса. В вашем случаи это просто дурной тон коддинга.

Comment: Если вкратце, то чем больше подчеркиваний, тем меньше автор хочет, чтобы это когда-нибудь трогали. Никакой конвенции нет, но языки зачастую это подстегивают запретами (PHP) и предложениями (питон) так делать (пых на самом деле только в документации запрещает).

Comment: В многих языках таким способом обозначены системные ф-и, переменные и константы. Также, зачастую, нижним подчеркиванием пользуються в ООП для обозначения приватных методов и полей классов, например:

    class SomeClass {
    private:
        int _x;
        void _doSomething();
    public:
        int x;
        void doSomething();
    };

Comment: Во внутренних регламентах вполне удобно вводить разные обозначения для синтаксиса, этого никто не запрещает. Работать с таким кодом порой удобнее, если не перебарщивать))

Answer (score 2):

В JS нижнее подчеркивание используется чтобы обозначить приватные методы или свойства классов.